# L2TP client for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, pptp, l2tp

It's easy enough to get a pptp client going on a Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty) desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp
```

However, I can't seem to find documentation find a corresponding L2TP client to connect to our Windows VPN server at work remotely.  I have a certificate from our offline CA (pkcs12 format with the public/private keys + CA public cert in one file), and in Windows I'd simply install via the MMC certificates snap-in, choose L2TP connection in the native client, and I'd be good to go.

Anyone have any ideas about setting up L2TP in Ubuntu?  Or should I just use PPTP -- my understanding is that it's much less secure than L2TP, but is that still true?  Will I need to ensure EAP authentication if I do stick with PPTP?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: In 2018 you can use `network-manager-l2tp` - see my [answer / notes here](https://serverfault.com/questions/344768/strongswan-ipsec-ubuntu-ignoring-informational-payload-type-no-proposal-chosen/901183#901183).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this guide, pretty comprehensive: http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/linux-l2tp.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you much, here is the a package for doing [l2tp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty/xl2tpd) and here is a [howto](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/freeswan-l2tp.html) that make be able to help you.

Comment: Haven't been able to get it to work yet, but I think this is as good as it gets.  Wishing for a "network-manager-l2tp" but not holding my breath.

Answer (score 1):

In **2018** you can use `network-manager-l2tp` - see [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/344768/strongswan-ipsec-ubuntu-ignoring-informational-payload-type-no-proposal-chosen/901183#901183) for connecting to a Windows VPN server from Linux.

Comment: This only shows you how to connect via PSK but this question is about connecting using certificate authentication, any idea if network-manager-l2tp even supports it as I've been struggling with this myself