# Using Ubuntu Karmic as an L2TP Client for VPN

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, ipsec, ubuntu-9.10, l2tp

I'm trying to connect to a VPN service over L2TP using Karmic as a client and it's not working.

The only details I have are the remote IP address, username & password, and a shared secret string; this is enough for Windows but doesn't appear to be enough for Ubuntu.

I've tried using network-manager-vpnc and vpnc from the terminal to connect and I get "no supported authentication", and trying with OpenSwan it says "unable to identify either side of the connection".

I'd really appreciate some help here if anyone else has implemented this successfully.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate except that is the following is for Jaunty: http://serverfault.com/questions/10671/l2tp-client-for-ubuntu-jaunty .  I'm not going to vote for close though because I am hopeful there have maybe been some new developments in this.

Comment: Can you post the actual error log

Answer (score 0):

Good luck.

IPSEC+L2TP is a beast to get working. The last resort first: [this guide](http://www.jacco2.dds.nl/networking/linux-l2tp.html) is fairly exhaustive.

If you're comfortable compiling things and moving libraries around, you can try [my NetworkManager plugin](https://github.com/geocar/NetworkManager-l2tp) which works at least with SonicWall's GroupVPN when set reasonably Windows+Mac compatible.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just try and use an ssh tunnel to imitate a VPN, Heres a guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN .

Comment: I don't have SSH access to that server (or a server in that location). Thanks for the answer though, I really appreciate it after so long.