# how i can use windows vpn connection file in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, vpn, ubuntu-10.04, l2tp

i have a windows vpn. how i can use this vpn in Ubuntu 10.04. i don't what's this vpn gateway or other configuration items.

my VPN file content is:

```
[usa]
    
Encoding=1
Type=2
AutoLogon=0
UseRasCredentials=1
DialParamsUID=14405859
Guid=0ED19D66025F914DAA2A030FDD4F0354
BaseProtocol=1
VpnStrategy=2
ExcludedProtocols=0
LcpExtensions=1
DataEncryption=8
SwCompression=1
NegotiateMultilinkAlways=0
SkipNwcWarning=0
SkipDownLevelDialog=0
SkipDoubleDialDialog=0
DialMode=1
DialPercent=75
DialSeconds=120
HangUpPercent=10
HangUpSeconds=120
OverridePref=15
RedialAttempts=3
RedialSeconds=60
IdleDisconnectSeconds=0
RedialOnLinkFailure=0
CallbackMode=0
CustomDialDll=
CustomDialFunc=
CustomRasDialDll=
AuthenticateServer=0
ShareMsFilePrint=1
BindMsNetClient=1
SharedPhoneNumbers=0
GlobalDeviceSettings=0
PrerequisiteEntry=
PrerequisitePbk=
PreferredPort=VPN4-0
PreferredDevice=WAN Miniport (L2TP)
PreferredBps=0
PreferredHwFlow=1
PreferredProtocol=1
PreferredCompression=1
PreferredSpeaker=1
PreferredMdmProtocol=0
PreviewUserPw=1
PreviewDomain=0
PreviewPhoneNumber=0
ShowDialingProgress=1
ShowMonitorIconInTaskBar=1
CustomAuthKey=-1
AuthRestrictions=296
TypicalAuth=2
IpPrioritizeRemote=1
IpHeaderCompression=0
IpAddress=0.0.0.0
IpDnsAddress=0.0.0.0
IpDns2Address=0.0.0.0
IpWinsAddress=0.0.0.0
IpWins2Address=0.0.0.0
IpAssign=1
IpNameAssign=1
IpFrameSize=1006
IpDnsFlags=0
IpNBTFlags=1
TcpWindowSize=0
UseFlags=0
IpSecFlags=0
IpDnsSuffix=
NETCOMPONENTS=
ms_server=1
ms_msclient=1
ms_psched=1
MEDIA=rastapi
Port=VPN4-0
Device=WAN Miniport (L2TP)
DEVICE=vpn
PhoneNumber=173.244.171.42
AreaCode=
CountryCode=1
CountryID=1
UseDialingRules=0
Comment=
LastSelectedPhone=0
PromoteAlternates=0
TryNextAlternateOnFail=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try searching before posting?
This might have some of the answers to help you learn how to do it.

[L2TP client for Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/10671/l2tp-client-for-ubuntu-jaunty)