# StrongSwan ipsec ubuntu "ignoring informational payload, type NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN"

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, cisco, ipsec

I have StrongSwan running on a ubuntu server and I'm trying to create an ipsec encrypted VPN tunnel with a Cisco 2821 router .  The connection is not working and I cannot figure out why.  It appears to complete phase 1, but fails at phase 2.  Can anyone provide suggestions?  I'm stumped.  BTW, my server is in the amazon cloud.

Here is my config:

```
conn my-conn
        type=tunnel
        authby=secret
        auth=esp
        ikelifetime=86400s
        keylife=3600s
        esp=3des-sha1
        ike=3des-sha1-modp1024
        keyexchange=ike
        pfs=no
        forceencaps=yes
        # Left security gateway, subnet behind it, nexthop toward right.
        left=10.0.0.4
        leftsubnet=10.0.0.4/32
        leftnexthop=%defaultroute
        # Right security gateway, subnet behind it, nexthop toward left.
        right=1.2.3.4   
        rightsubnet=1.2.3.5/32
        rightnexthop=%defaultroute
        # To authorize this connection, but not actually start it,
        # at startup, uncomment this.
        auto=start
```

Here is the output from the logs:

```
Dec 28 18:02:19 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: initiating Main Mode
Dec 28 18:02:19 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-03]
Dec 28 18:02:19 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: enabling possible NAT-traversal with method RFC 3947
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: ignoring Vendor ID payload [Cisco-Unity]
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: received Vendor ID payload [Dead Peer Detection]
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: ignoring Vendor ID payload [883f3a4fb4782a3ae88bf05cdfe38ae0]
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: received Vendor ID payload [XAUTH]
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: NAT-Traversal: Result using draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02/03: i am NATed
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: | protocol/port in Phase 1 ID Payload is 17/0. accepted with port_floating NAT-T
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: Peer ID is ID_IPV4_ADDR: '1.2.3.4'
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: ISAKMP SA established
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #331: initiating Quick Mode PSK+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+UP {using isakmp#330}
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: ignoring informational payload, type NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
Dec 28 18:02:20 myserver pluto[15753]: "my-conn" #330: ignoring informational payload, type IPSEC_RESPONDER_LIFETIME
```

The config given to me to connect to the cisco router was:

```
Key Management: IKE 
Diffie-Hellman Group:   Group 2 
Encryption Algorithm:   3DES (rec)  
Hash Algorithm: SHA-1 (rec.)    
Authentication Method:  Preshared   
Pre-Shared Secret Key:  TBC 
Life Time:  86400s (24h)    

Encryption Phase 2 (IPSec):     

Encapsulation:  ESP 
Encryption Algorithm used:  3DES (rec)  
Hash Algorithm: SHA-1 (rec.)    
Perfect Forward Secrecy:    Groupe 2    
Aggressive Mode:    NO  
Life Time:  3600s (1h)
```

Comment: Can you provide the Cisco config, and its logs?

Comment: I put in a request for the config/logs but its doubtful I'll get them anytime soon

Comment: Well, have they provided you with cryptography, lifetime, and keying configurations at least?  Those will need to be a match with what you've configured on your side, or you'll get connection failures due to no acceptable proposals - which would match to the logs that you're seeing.

Comment: I've added the config parameters given to me in my initial post

Comment: The only mismatch I see there is PFS - change your `pfs=no` to `pfs=yes` and `pfsgroup=modp1024`, and give that a shot.  Also, I'd recommend verifying with them that NAT traversal is enabled on their end, since it's triggering in your logs.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but I get the same output in the logs that the connection fails.  Am I correct in saying that phase1 is completing but phase 2 fails?  Do you know where it may be failing?  My reading suggests that it is the cisco router that is reject my esp crypto settings.  Also, i should mention that I have another vpn connection already up on this server and it uses PSK.   Thanks for your advice

Comment: Correct, phase 1 is working and phase 2 is not.  Your phase 2 settings now match what they've provided; however, you do need to check on NAT traversal.  If they haven't explicitly enabled it on their end then the connection will fail.  Beyond that, the logs from the remote device will need to be looked it.

Comment: I'll ask for the config on the Cisco router to enable nat.  Thanks a lot, I'll probably have the cicsco config by tommorrow

Comment: Similar issue here but with libreswan driven by NetworkManager-openswan. I've seen a working setup and compared the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` file with no apparent difference. But I don't have the exact same versions of tools on the Gentoo box as it was on the colleague's Fedora box.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, Amazon EC2 uses some NAT to make your instance reachable from the Internet.

While NAT-friendly applications will work seamlessly (think http or ssh), some protocols were designed at a time where end-to-end comunication was the rule, and NAT will break these protocols.

FTP, or SIP (rtp actually) use dynamically-chosen ports, but helpers were designed. STUN for VoIP for example.

In the case of IPSec, phase 1 is successful. This is NAT detection. So your server says in the logs `i am NATed`.

However, phase 2, which is NAT traversal decision, fails. You may have to enable what Cisco calls 'IPSec NAT Transparency' on both sides. The ipsec payload is thereby not at a layer 3 level (IP), but at layer 4, in UDP.

This is somewhat similar to what openvpn does,  but with ssl instead of IPSec.

Have a look at [Cisco's site regarding NAT traversal](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2t/12_2t13/feature/guide/ftipsnat.html). While cisco-centric, it will help you set up your tunnel.

Comment: I have the same issue, and Cisco NAT traversal is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I received this error with StrongSwan `5.6.1` in Centos 7 while connecting to a Windows server. The error is due to the **remote server using weak ciphers** that are considered **deprecated by StrongSwan**.

- Enabling the following **weak ciphers** allows the `ipsec` connection to
  complete:

  - Phase1 Algorithms : `aes128-sha1-modp2048,3des-sha1-modp1536,3des-sha1-modp1024`
  - Phase2 Algorithms : `aes128-sha1,3des-sha1`

[image]

see the [known issues for network-manager-l2tp](https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/wiki/Known-Issues)

---

I found the [Arch Linux L2TP wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Openswan_L2TP/IPsec_VPN_client_setup) helpful & the instructions although for **OpenSwan** *also work* on **StrongSwan**:

- Run `ipsec verify` first to configure your environment.
- Run `xl2tpd -D` (debug mode) - to confirm your settings are sane.
- Give the VPN the same name in the **NetworkManager applet** that you give the `conn` setting in `/etc/ipsec.conf`
- The `network-manager-l2tp` plugin seems to establish  the matching `L2TP` connection via the `lns` ip address in `/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf`. The name you give the `[lac vpn-name]` setting does not seem to matter to the plugin.
- These notes also apply to setting up **L2TP** with `ipsec` under **Arch Linux**. Use **Libreswan** (**Strongswan** `ipsec` does not work in Arch Linux) with the `network-manager-l2tp` plugin & place your `ipsec` connection details under `/etc/ipsec.d/*.conf`. The filename can be anything as the plugin searches for a `conn` string in the config files that matches the **VPN name** in **NetworkManager**.